# typo3 add custom css to bootstrap package

Tags: typo3

I try to add custom css classes to bootstrap package included in Typo3 6.2.
In my root template page, I add in the Setup section the following code:

```
page = PAGE
page.includeCSS.myCustomStylesheet = fileadmin/template/css/custom.css
```

but this typoscript has no effect in my source code, as if nothing is written.

Actually, when I include Bootstrap Package template in static template, every Basis templates are removed.

Any idea on how to proceed?

[image]

Edit: In bootstrap package, all CSS stylesheets are merged into a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the »EXT:«-string in your path is a shortcut to the extension-directory (»./typo3conf/ext/«). So in your example you would have an extension called »path_to_my_css«.

But i guess you probably uploaded a stylesheet into your filelist. If so, then click on the file to the see full path (like »http://example.com/fileadmin/templates/assets/css/bootstrap.css)«

Then set the correct path like this

```
page.includeCSS.myCustomStylesheet = fileadmin/templates/assets/css/bootstrap.css
```

You will now see a link to your file with an appended hash in the HTML sourcecode

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fileadmin/templates/assets/css/bootstrap.css?1350898986" media="all">
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a solution on the github site of the bootstrap package.
The problem is the default css concatenation and compression. If you deactivate it by

```
config.concatenateCss = 0
```

the css will be correctly included.

Source: https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/issues/33

There is a similar option for Javascript files:

```
config.concatenateJs = 0
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked with me. Thanx